# Batch cmd won't accept redirect symbol

Tags: batch-file, cmd, escaping

I have a batch script that's running a command that should forward the result to a file:

```
start cmd /k "tasklist | find ^"Notepad^" ^> ^"C:\Users\Improvise\Desktop\notepadDeets.txt^""
```

The following works in the cmd prompt:

```
tasklist | find "Notepad" > "C:\Users\Improvise\Desktop\notepadDeets.txt"
```

In this script, the command will work like so:

```
start cmd /k "tasklist | find ^"Notepad^""
```

But when I try to add the `> "C:\Users\Improvise\Desktop\notepadDeets.txt"`.

With `^>` the error msg is:

```
Access denied - >
```

With `>` the error msg is:

```
FIND: Parameter format not correct
```

Am I not escaping this character correctly? Why does it not work in the batch script, and how can I get it to work?

Comment: Why are you using `start` in the .bat file script?

Comment: It's actually part of a larger bat script that does all sorts of stuff. I thought this was the syntax for executing commands. I have another `start cmd /k "..."` in this same bat file that works fine.

Comment: No need to escpape the inner quotes or the redirection.  Just use quotes like you normally would and continue to surround the entire command in quotes.

Comment: I see no point in using `START` or `CMD /K`.  Why would you want to leave an open cmd window sitting there?

Comment: I have to use quotes around the process name because it contains spaces. I just put Notepad here so that anyone could reproduce it

Comment: What is your point?  I didn't tell you not to use quotes.  I said use quotes just like you normally would.  I have no idea why you chose to try to escape them and the redirection symbol.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to escape special characters inside the outer quotes. From `cmd /?`:

> [...] Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and remove the last quote character on the command line [...]

The following will work:

```
start cmd /k "tasklist | find /I "Notepad" >"C:\Users\Improvise\Desktop\notepadDeets.txt""
```

Or, without all-enclosing quotes, and with the special characters escaped:

```
start cmd /k tasklist ^| find /I "Notepad" ^>"C:\Users\Improvise\Desktop\notepadDeets.txt"
```

---

[ *EDIT* ]   The following explains the errors quoted in the original post.

> With `^>` the error msg is:
>
> ```
> Access denied - >
> ```

With `^>` the unescaped `>` is passed to the `find` command, which interprets it as a filename to search. That fails because `>` is an illegal filename, and is reported as an "*access denied*" error for some reason. Variations of the same error can be duplicated at the command prompt:

```
C:\etc>find "notepad" ^>
Access denied - >

C:\etc>find "notepad" ^> nul
Access denied - >
File not found - NUL

C:\etc>find "notepad" ^>nul
File not found - >NUL
```

> With `>` the error msg is:
>
> ```
> FIND: Parameter format not correct
> ```

With an unescaped `>` the redirection applies to the top level `start` command, so what gets executed is `cmd /k "tasklist | find ^"Notepad"`, which in the end runs `find ^"Notepad` causing the "*parameter format not correct*" error:

```
C:\etc>find ^"Notepad
FIND: Parameter format not correct
```